# Prompt the user for a number between 1 and 9, then prints a square of text

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, formatting, type-conversion

How can I write a program that prompts the user for a number between 1 and 9, inclusive, then prints a square of text to the console that looks like this:

```
1****
22***
333**
4444*
55555
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np

b_num = raw_input()
b_num = int(b_num)

mat = np.zeros((b_num, b_num)).tolist()
mat = np.char.mod('%.5g', mat)
mat[0:9] = '*'

for i in range(b_num):
        for a in range(i):
                mat[i, a] = i + 1
                mat[0:0] = '1'

mat = '\n'.join(map(str, mat))
mat = mat.replace(']', '')
mat = mat.replace('[', '')
mat = mat.replace('\'', '')
mat = mat.replace(' ', '')

print mat
```

Currently this outputs an array as follows which is a success:

```
1****
22***
333**
4444*
55555
```

I can't help but wonder if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Elegant or not is opinion, at least your code works like you want and expect it too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a format specifier to print the appropriate box:

```
>>> n = int(input())     # raw_input() Py2
5
>>> for i in range(1, n+1):
...     print("{:*<{width}}".format(str(i)*i, width=n))
1****
22***
333**
4444*
55555
```

This uses `{:*<{width}}` which means fill with `*`, left justify `<`, with the width of `{width}` - which is a variable passed in to the format function `width=n`

Comment: ahh that is a major improvement!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
b_num = raw_input()
b_num = int(b_num)

for b in xrange(1,b_num+1):
    print("".join((str(b) if i < b else '*' for i in xrange(b_num))))
```

At least to me, this is elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Elegant is subjective but trying to do it with less lines I'd possibly do something like this.

```
import numpy as np

b_num = int(input("What Number?"))

arr = np.array([str(i)*i + "*"*(b_num-i)for i in range(1,b_num+1)])
```

Comment: totally fascinating